# Is Bound By A Thought They Didn’t Fully Say But Verbally Came Into Agreement With It?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot

Is one bound by something that came to mind that they came in agreement with verbally? For example, a thought enters into one’s mind and they say “amen” or “I will.” Are they then bound by that thing?

Comment: related: [Making a neder without specifying verbally](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29448/11501)